# clojure source code position in macros

Tags: parsing, error-handling, clojure, macros

For my macros I need to get information about source code position for some sub symbol in complex form for correct errors reporting. I can use :line :column metas for more complex parts, such as sub-lists, but not for symbols. Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah... this is a problem with symbols, strings, etc... If you need to use source code analysis, you can try [rewrite-clj](https://github.com/xsc/rewrite-clj). That will have information on the postitioning